# Adding a X delay to video capture

Tags: python, opencv

For my studies I'm reasearching possibilities with openCV, now I try to make the `cv2.videoCapture(0)` having the reading of images, being stored in a buffer or something similar for 15sec and then show them on screen with `cv2.imshow()` from the frame buffer.

I have no clue how to buffer my video feed, for context I want to be able to delay my webcam to create a video feedback system for my juggling training.

So doing a trick and then having some seconds to reach the screen and have a feedback of what I've just done.

Here is the way I capture my webcam at the moment, it's very basic though :

```
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

# Adding the frames to a buffer somewhere here in the script.

while True:

    frame = cap.read()

    cv2.imshow("frame", frame)

    key = cv2.waitKey(1)
    if key == 27:
        break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

All help and resources given will be much appreciated.

Comment: Use `time.sleep()` to add a delay

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the snippet I ended up to video playback of webcam feed : (python)
It is just storing frames in a list and poping them every "DELAY_SECONDS".

```
import cv2
import time

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
print(cap.get(3))
print(cap.get(4))

start_time = time.time()

frames = []

DELAY_SECONDS = 5

while True:

    ret, frame = cap.read()
    frames.append(frame)

    if time.time() - start_time > DELAY_SECONDS:
        cv2.imshow("frame", frames.pop(0))

    key = cv2.waitKey(1)
    if key == 27:
        break
```

Thanks for helping I how my snippet can help some of you !

Answer (score 0):

I think it's more convenient (and easier) to just record the video to a file. You can then play that file back. I threw some code together from these [tutorials](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_gui/py_video_display/py_video_display.html).
Press 'r' and the recording starts. When you're done press 'q'. Then press 'p' to play the video back. To retry, just press 'r' again to overwrite the previous video file. The added advantage is that you can keep a video if you want to.
You can easily expand this code with extra functionality (and input checks - there are none!), but it might be enough to suit your needs.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

def rec():
    # record a video
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
    # Define the codec and create VideoWriter object
    fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'XVID')
    out = cv2.VideoWriter('output.avi',fourcc, 30.0, (640,480))

    while(cap.isOpened()):
        ret, frame = cap.read()
        if ret==True:
            out.write(frame)
            cv2.imshow('frame',frame)
            if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
                break
        else:
            break

    # Release everything if job is finished
    cap.release()
    out.release()

def playback():
    # play a video
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture('output.avi')

    while(cap.isOpened()):
        ret, frame = cap.read()
        if ret:
            cv2.imshow('frame',frame)
        else:
            break
        if cv2.waitKey(30) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            break

    cap.release()

# create empty window to process input
cv2.namedWindow('frame')
# main loop
while True:
    key = cv2.waitKey(10) 
    if key == ord('r'):
        rec()
    elif key == ord('p'):
        playback()
    elif key == ord('x'):
        # end main loop
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Thank you for sharing this piece of code I'll be able to assemble what I need with this and what I came up with :D